# using hint in oracle sql query for tuning

Tags: sql

I was trying to tune a oracle sql query. One of my friends suggested me to use HINTS. I was in lack of time so was not able to check out the syntax. From an existing sql i wrote a query and shared it with my lead. Now i want to know if its alright.

Existing query: `select columnName from tableName`

My query: `select +columnName from tableName`

The sample that i have mentioned above is just the logic that i implemented. It was part of a bhi query and adding a plus symbol before the columnName in the select condition reduced the run time of the query. Now i know that it is not the proper implementation of Hints. I want to know if the above is a form of tuning for sql code. If adding a plus symbol to the columnName helps in anyway to the sql performance or is it that adding the plus does not affect the sql performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plus sign in front of the column has nothing to do with performance. It is merely syntactic sugar and changes absolutely nothing.

If you really want to use hints, you need to put them in to a comment.

```
select /*+ some_hint */ columnName
from tableName;
```

For a detailed list of hints and how they work please refer to the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#i35922